# Script to parse a csv file and get out put to search windows directory

Tags: batch-file

I am writing a script to satisfy following conditions:

1. I have a csv file with 2 columns, I need to read the file line by line and take values from second column only , lets say values are test1, test2 etc.
2. Once I have the values, I want to search a windows directory as *test1*.log etc.
3. If I get a match against any entry during the search, I want to copy the item to another windows dir.

I have the input file and the search directory is constant as well as file name format is constant.

I used following script:

```
@ECHO OFF
FOR /f "tokens=2 delims=," %%b IN (test.txt) DO^
  ( dir *%b%*.log IN "D:\test" if
     (*%b%*.log = "" echo "file not found" )
 Else DO xcopy "D:\test\"*%b%*.log C:\dest )
```

But, I can't run the code.
Please help.

Comment: _I can't run the code_ means what exactly? Error message?

Comment: When I run the script, I get "the syntax of the command is incorrect"

Comment: it's your `if` syntax. The `(` has to be on the same line than `if`, `) else (` has to be on one line.

Comment: Also your `%b%` need to be `%%b`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an example to help you:

```bat
@Echo Off

Set "InFile=test.txt"
Set "ChkDir=D:\test"
Set "SavDir=C:\dest"

If Not Exist "%ChkDir%\" GoTo :EOF
If /I Not "%CD%"=="%SavDir%" (CD /D "%SavDir%" 2>Nul||GoTo :EOF)

For /F "UseBackQ Tokens=2 Delims=," %%A In ("%InFile%"
) Do If Exist "%ChkDir%\*%%~A*.log" (Copy /Y "%ChkDir%\*%%~A*.log">Nul 2>&1
) Else Echo "%ChkDir%\*%%~A*.log not found"

Pause
```

Answer (score 0):

Still a bit unclear, maybe this works:

```
@ECHO OFF
FOR /f "tokens=2 delims=," %%b IN (test.txt
) DO If not exist "D:\test\*%%b*.log" (
    echo "file "D:\test\*%%b*.log" not found" 
) Else (
    xcopy "D:\test\*%%b*.log" C:\dest 
)
```